# Filter Django Queryset_A with Queryset_B based on a specifict one property with the same value

Tags: python, django

1. Filter Model_A with Model_B
2. Return Items of Model_A

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.CharField()

class Model_B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    location = models.CharField()

def some_filter_function():
    return [list of Model_A items based on Model_B.name]
```

Comment: This is *one* of the *many* reasons why you should use a `ForeignKey`...

Comment: Hi Willem, thanks for your prompt response... what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

considering you can't change the Model to use foreignkey, you can try something like this:

```
    my_items = []
    names = Model_b.objects.all()
    for name in names:
        name_b = name.name
        model_a = Model_a.objects.filter(name = name)
           for item in model_a:
               my_items.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @William Van Onsam.

If you define your `Model_A` like

```
class Model_B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    location = models.CharField()

class Model_A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.CharField()
    b = models.ForeignKey(Model_B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # NOTE you need to declare Model_B prior to Model_A, 
    # and then you can use Model_B as a parameter here.
```

Then you can do

```
def some_filter_function():
    b = get_model_b()
    return Model_A.objects.filter(name=b.name)
```

in your view function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach.

```
def some_filter_function():
    queryset = None
    if Model_B.objects.filter(name="Jorge").exists()
        queryset = Model_A.objects.all()
    return queryset
```